# In Dart, does `List.unmodifiable` create an unmodifiable view, or a whole new independent list?

Tags: list, performance, dictionary, dart, collections

1. In Dart, do `List.unmodifiable(someList)` and `Map.unmodifiable(someMap)` create an unmodifiable **view**, or a whole new independent list/map? I am guessing it's a new independent list, but I must be sure.

   - If it's a view, modifications to the original list will modify the now not so unmodifiable list, but sometimes you are just discarding the original anyway, and creating a view is much faster.
2. And, in case they create independent lists/maps, is there some way to create an unmodifiable view, for performance purposes?

   - **Update**: Ok, I have answered my own question number 2, by finding this: [`UnmodifiableListView<E>` Docs](https://api.dartlang.org/stable/1.23.0/dart-collection/UnmodifiableListView-class.html). But I still need to know the answer to the other questions.
3. What's the Big O for creating a dart list from another one, including the one created by `List.unmodifiable(someList)`? For example, this is the info for Java collections: [Big O for Java Collections](https://gist.github.com/FedericoPonzi/8d5094dbae33cbb94536a73f62d1c1a0).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

1. The items are copied. It's a whole new independent list.
2. See [Dart Collection Library](https://api.dart.dev/dart-collection/dart-collection-library.html), more specifically:

   - `UnmodifiableListView`
   - `UnmodifiableMapView`
3. It's `O(N)` – it copies all elements, so it has to visit each element.

   - If you use `List.unmodifiable` from another list, it knows the target length, so it won't have to resize the list it's creating as it's iterating.

Comment: Sorry, I need answers to questions 1 and 3.

Comment: I must admit #1 was in fact a stupid question, because I could have just checked that myself by making a copy and then changing the contents of the original list and seeing if the contents of the second would change or not. But then I decided to let the question stand, as documentation (mostly for Java programmers who are used to make unmodifiable views only).

Comment: What does a `View` mean in dart, I'm sure it's not related to the `Views` in Android, right?

Comment: @Dennis : A view in this context means a "way of looking" to something as if it's something else. In this case you *view* the list as unmodifiable, even though it's not. You don't create a new list internally in memory, since the View is backed by the original list.

Comment: @MarcG It's not a stupid question. Its pretty valuable to have this stuff documented in it's entirety on SO. :-)